# NWConnection SSDP Discovery not receiving data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, udp, ssdp

I'm trying to do an SSDP Discovery broadcast and unable to get reply data from NWConnection.receive.

Network.framework is relatively new and there is not a lot of info out there. What I'm missing here?

SSDP Discovery broadcast was sent and a UPnP device replied. (Wireshark screenshot below)
[image]

```
    import Foundation
    import Network

    let connection = NWConnection(host: "239.255.255.250", port: 1_900, using: .udp)

    func sendBroadcast() {
        let message = """
            M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
            ST: ssdp:all
            HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900
            MAN: ssdp:discover
            MX: 1
            """.data(using: .utf8)

        connection.send(content: message, completion: .contentProcessed { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Send Error: \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("Broadcast sent")
                }
            }
        )
    }

    connection.stateUpdateHandler = { newState in
        switch newState {
        case .setup:
            print("Connection: Setup")
        case .preparing:
             print("Connection: Preparing")
        case .waiting:
            print("Connection: Waiting")
        case .ready:
            print("Connection: Ready")
            sendBroadcast()
        case .failed:
            print("Connection: Failed")
        case .cancelled:
            print("Connection: Cancelled")
        }
    }

    connection.receive(minimumIncompleteLength: 2, maximumLength: 4_096) { data, context, isComplete, error in
        /// This is never executed
        ///
        print(data ?? "", context ?? "", isComplete, error ?? "")
    }

    connection.viabilityUpdateHandler = { update in
        print(update)
    }

    connection.betterPathUpdateHandler = { path in
        print(path)
    }

    connection.start(queue: .main)

    RunLoop.main.run()
```

Comment: Thanks for the NWconnection example, even if this one doesn’t work.  It looks like NWconnection programming is going to be easier than CFnetwork once we get used to it.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out **Network.framework** does not support **UDP Broadcasts** yet (Feb 2019)
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/316357#316357

Comment: iOS 14 beta now has support for multicasts, which seems like it will be of interest to you https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/104724

Answer (score 0):

With `UDP` try this method instead:

```
connection.receiveMessage { (data, context, isComplete, error) in

    print(data ?? "", context ?? "", isComplete, error ?? "")
}
```

Here is a good example of it in [use here](https://gist.github.com/paulw11/e672a59c68762b82a5421f365a579e2d)

I had the opposite problem with `TCP` and was using `connection.receiveMessage(...)` and the same thing was happening -**the callback was never entered**. I posted a question in [Apple Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/669062?answerId=651917022#651917022). It turns out with `TCP` you can only use:

```
connection.receive(minimumIncompleteLength: 1, maximumLength: 65535) { data, context, isComplete, error in
    
    print(data ?? "", context ?? "", isComplete, error ?? "")
}
```

An Apple Developer Technical Support Specialist named [eskimo answered it here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/120486):

**. TCP is not a message-oriented protocol, and thus**

```
receiveMessage(…)
```

**doesn’t make any sense. What you want is**

```
receive(minimumIncompleteLength:maximumLength:completion:)
```

That being said, with `UDP` try `connection.receiveMessage(…)`